# What's the purpose of Shadowing?

Tags: c#, c++, shadowing

I recently read an article about **shadowing** or **hiding** in programming (C++, C#, VB).

But I still don't get what's the reason of those? Why would we do something like that? I mean we can always call the real function if we want it to return the value, and not casting some class to it.

Well, I am not much a very very good at programming so I can't see the reason:)

Anyone can explain?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shadowing the child class has its own version of the method providing different implementation, the same method is also available in the base class.

Suppose you have class library being used by various modules in a project. There is a method which is being referenced other libraries. if we make a change in method it may break existing functionality. Hence we hide/shadow the method using new keyword. This way we are able achieve  new functionality without breaking old functionality.

EDIT:
You can also find a great example on Eric Lippert's blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/21/method-hiding-apologia.aspx).

Comment: You can also find a great example on Eric Lippert's blog [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/21/method-hiding-apologia.aspx)

Comment: Why is it in the first place we gonna name those function with similar name and having exactly similar attributes?

Comment: Eric Lippert's blog above give a damn good explanation :). Thank you

Comment: Adding the link to answer.